# Comma-separated array of integers instead of newline array of integers

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, command-line, integer

I want to create a comma-separated array of column numbers of my input file stored as a variable.

For example, if my input file contains 4 columns, to store 1,2,3,4 as a variable comma_arr, and so that after that i can pass that comma_arr further as a variable.

I have used this code:

```
clm=$(
    awk -F"\t" '{print NF}' clm.tsv |
        sort -nu |
        tail -n 1) &&
        arr=($(seq 1 $((clm)))) &&
        IFS=',' comma_arr="${arr[*]}" &&
        echo "${comma_arr[*]}"

)
```

I have also tried using `echo "${comma_arr[@]}"`, but instead of getting 1,2,3,4 I get these numbers each in a new line, like this:

1
2
3
4

The input file (clm.tsv) looks like this):

```
DA NE UNKNOWN BLA
YES NO NA,NA LOL
YES NO NA,NA LOL
YES NO NA,NA LOL
```

I have tried lots of different combinations and all of them return me new line list. I am not sure what to try next. If it's helpful, command `declare -p comma_arr` returns `typeset comma_arr=$'1\n2\n3\n4'`.

Comment: use `@` instead of `*` in your arrays

Comment: I have tried it, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: You should show us sample of `clm.tsv`

Answer (score 4):

```
comma_arr=$(awk -F'\t' -v OFS=',' 'NR==1 {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=i; print}' clm.tsv)
```

Use only awk, and only on the first line of the input file. Set input field separator to tab, output field separator to comma, replace all fields by their index, and print.

Answer (score 3):

> if my input file contains 4 columns, to store 1,2,3,4 as a variable comma_arr, and so that after that i can pass that comma_arr further as a variable.

```
comma_arr=$(awk -F"\t" 'NR==1{print NF}' clm.tsv | xargs seq 1 | paste -sd,)
```

Answer (score 2):

What I would do:

```
$ comma_arr=$(
    awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"}NR==1{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print i}' clm.tsv |
    paste -sd ,
)

$ echo "$comma_arr"
1,2,3,4
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility might be:

```
comma_arr=$(seq -s, $(head -n1 clm.tsv | tr '\t' '\n' | wc -l))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do a lot more than just commas :

> ```
> jot -s ',' 7
> ```

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

you can making it literally have a curvature :

> ```
> jot -s $'\f\b\b\b\b' 20 -399093 99999
> ```

```
-399093
   -372825
      -346557
         -320289
            -294021
               -267753
                  -241485
                     -215217
                        -188949
                           -162681
                              -136413
                                 -110145
                                    -83877
                                      -57609
                                        -31341
                                          -5073
                                           21195
                                            47463
                                             73731
                                              99999
```

or with hex down a staircase

> ```
> jot -s $'\v\b\b\b\b\\___' -w '%X' 17 65535 4367
> ```

```
FFFF
\___F110
    \___E221
        \___D332
            \___C443
                \___B554
                    \___A665
                        \___9776
                            \___8887
                                \___7998
                                    \___6AA9
                                        \___5BBA
                                            \___4CCB
                                                \___3DDC
                                                    \___2EED
                                                        \___1FFE
                                                            \___110F
```